# Spark warehouse directory is empty

Tags: apache-spark

I have created a Spark session with `enableHiveSupport()` and configure `spark.sql.warehouse.dir` and write data to HDFS with `saveAsTable()`. As I expected, there are some metadata is created and stored under the directory `spark.sql.warehouse.dir` but I found nothing.

My environment: `Spark 3.1.2, Python 3.7, PySpark 3.1.2`
Spark cluster is deployed with `standalone mode`

```py
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .option("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "hdfs://hdfs_cluster/spark_warehouse_dir")\
    .appName("AddDataToWarehouse") \
    .enableHiveSupport()\    
    .getOrCreate()

data = [("John", 25), ("Mary", 30), ("Tom", 35)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["name", "age"])
df.write.mode("overwrite").format("hive").option(
    "path",
    "hdfs://hdfs_cluster/demo/people_data").saveAsTable("people"
)

df2 = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM people")
df2.show()
```

After saving data, I tried to show tables:
[image: show tables after saving data]
The directory `hdfs://hdfs_cluster/spark_warehouse_dir` is empty after table `people` is created by using `saveAsTable("people")`. Then when I'm using another SparkSession to read data from this table I got exceptions cause there is no table named `people` is defined.

[image]
*I found that if I restart my current notebook (I use Jupyter to run my test), I can read data from table `people` because there is a directory named `metastore_db` is created on the same path with my notebook.*

How can I make Spark store the `metastore_db` on the `warehouse` directory in HDFS (`spark.sql.warehouse.dir`) instead of local file system?